# What is the difference between "tell me" and "I am told"?

Tags: passive-voice

What is the difference between "**they/people tell** **me**" and "**I** **am** **told**"? 
or Do they similarly indicate a passive meaning?

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of a sentence, ***tell me*** is a way of requesting information from someone:

> Tell me the truth.
> Tell me what happened.

At the end of a sentence, both phrases could be used to indicate someone has provided you information, but the structure of the sentence won't be exactly the same:

> The honey is good in these parts; that's what I am told.
> The honey is good in these parts; that's what the bears tell me.
>
> The army will be marching tomorrow, or so I am told.
> The army will be marching tomorrow, or at least that's what the officers tell me.

In a context like that, ***tell me*** requires you to indicate the source, but ***I am told*** does not.

That said, I'm sure the expressions can be used in plenty of other ways, which is why some have asked you to elaborate.

Comment: "Tell me the truth" Here, Doesn't **tell** **me** indicate a  passive meaning? like,tell me the true (by sb)

Comment: @Dinusha That is an imperative, with an implicit 2nd-person subject, the hearer.